Lombok - How to create a throwable default constructor for a @SuperBuilder
I am using the Lombok @SuperBuilder and am trying to create a default constructor in Lombok which can throw exceptions. The following code works:
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
private class SomeBuilderBase {
    private final String someString;
    
    protected SomeBuilderBase(SomeBuilderBaseBuilder<?,?> b) {
        someString = b.someString;
    }
}

When I make the default constructor throwable, I get the below exception thrown:
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
private class SomeBuilderBase {
    private final String someString;
    
    protected SomeBuilderBase(SomeBuilderBaseBuilder<?,?> b) throws Exception {
        someString = b.someString;
    }
}


error: unreported exception Exception in default constructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)

I suspect that this might be a limitation in Lombok at the moment of writing (I am using Lombok v1.18.32), but I'd like to know if there's anything I've missed in order to get this to work. Currently, I am delomoboking this, but it quickly gets ugly and quite hard to maintain.

I feel like this has something to do with Exception being checked. What happens if you declare the constrcutor to throw unchecked exception?

Thank you!! It worked with adding @SneakyThrows to the constructor.

As @Chaosfire mentioned in a comment, there is a workaround where the constructor throws unchecked exceptions (using @SneakyThrows):
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
private class SomeBuilderBase {
    private final String someString;

    @SneakyThrows
    protected SomeBuilderBase(SomeBuilderBaseBuilder<?,?> b) {
        someString = b.someString;
        if (someString.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
}

This works without compiler errors and generates the exception. However, it is not optimal, as we lose information on the problems the build() operation can cause. Nevertheless, the problem gets solved this way.
